# Error when I try to make a ManyToMany relation in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to make a ManyToMany relation in Doctrine with Symfony 2 between a group and an user : many users can be in many groups and many groups can have many users.

Then in my entities, i do this :

**Groupe.php**

```
/**
* Many Groups have Many clients.
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Client", mappedBy="groupe")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="client_groupe")
*/
private $clients;

 /**
 * Get clients
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getClients()
{
    return $this->clients;
}
```

**Client.php**

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Groupe", inversedBy="clients")     
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="client_groupe",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupe_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )

     */
    private $groupe;
```

but when I call the `getClients()` function on my entity `$groupe`, following error occured :

```
FROM client t0 WHERE client_groupe.groupe_id = ?' with params ["2"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'client_groupe.groupe_id' in 'where clause'
```

It doesn't add the `client_groupe` table in the from clause.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Try to remove `name="group_id"` and `name="client_id"` in your file client.php, so symfony can generate the column itself.

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `client_groupe` table in from clause. Try after removing `* @ORM\JoinTable(name="client_groupe")` from `Groupe.php`. Have a look at following working example of `ManyToMany` relationship scenario.

**Groupe.php**

```
/**
* Many Groups have Many clients
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Client", mappedBy="groupe")
*/
private $clients;
```

**Client.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ecommerce\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Groupe", inversedBy="clients")     
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="client_groupe",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="groupe_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $groupe;
```

`client_id` and `groupe_id` is fields of `client_groupe` table. Generate Getter and setter using doctrine command and update database using `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` command.